# Home Networking Rj45 from switch to faceplate

Tags: rj-45, ubiquiti

I'm currently running network cable from a central switch to different areas of the house. One room has an RJ45 faceplate, every other cable is running between locations connected to rj45 connectors.

I'm using this method to connect all my RJ45's:

[image: I'm using this method to connect all my RJ45's]

This is giving me full POE and 1GBPS down the cable which is perfect. However when i wire up a faceplate matching the same numbers i get POE but no connection.

I'm using a Ubiquiti 8-60 switch connected to a AP-AC-PRO in this case. Here is the faceplate I'm wiring into - not currently wired as I have it running straight into a rj45 connector to get the AP working in the meantime.

Faceplate I'm wiring into:

[image: Faceplate I'm wiring into]

Can anyone help? Hoping this is a simple solution!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a photo of the back if the wired faceplate? I observe that (ideally) you use different cables between faceplates to between cable ends (solid vs stranded), although this in and of itself does not explain your issue.  If the issue persists you can get cheap (like $10) rj45 continuity testers which are useful.

Comment: @davidgo - thanks for the response. Added the faceplate above - not currently wired but as mentioned I was matching numbers. Essentially i'm running straight though cables to the 568B standard, should this be a crossover? Seems like this is quite a niche topic as its hardly covered anywhere online :D

Comment: It should ideally be straight through but if it was wired as a crossover gigabit devices (but not 100 megabit ones) would negotiate a connection anyway. Can't help you much if we don't see how its wired up.

Comment: Rather then matching numbers ( I've never tried that!), match colours. For example blue with a white strip goes to blue pin, white with blue stripe goes to white&blue pin.

Comment: You want to follow the colours of the outer pins - ie the B standard.

Answer (score 4):

Once you've adopted a wiring standard (568B in your case), you should maintain it throughout your installation.
Wall plates are simply a convenient break in a run of cable, so pin 1 should follow with the same colour through each pin 1 all the way from end to end, etc. In your picture you'd be following the outer columns marked 'B' for the faceplate connections. If you did ever need a crossover connection this would be better handled by the final interconnect cable rather than cross wiring a wall plate, though in practice either approach would work.

Historically crossover cables were used when connecting directly bewtween similar devices (PC to PC, or Switch to Switch), allowing Receive to be connected directly to Transmit, whereas conventional connections (PC to switch) are already wired internally to handle that mapping. However nowadays any compliant Gigabit devices are required to sense and auto-negotiate an internal crossover when required, so there's no more need to use crossover cables when cascading modern switches.

It's fairly important to **maintain the pair twist** as far as possible, more so in higher bandwidth installations, so try to keep the pairs twisted all the way up to the punch down in the wall plate (or into the strain releif if you're fitting your own RJ45 ends). The pairs are actually twisted at different rates to minimise cross talk between pairs (brown pair usually has the slowest twist) so don't go mad and twist the ends like a tie wrap.

UTP cable comes in many variants (STP, UTP, Cat5, Cat6, solid core, multi strand, etc). In my experiance for a casual domestic installation it won't matter too much if these are mixed, and typically you'd use solid core for infrastructure (in walls behind faceplates) because it's better for the signal and once installed isn't prone to being flexed to cause fatigue fractures in the single copper strand. Whereas you'd use multistrand in any patch leads which are subject to repeated bending, they may still fracture individual strands but will be overlaid by adjacent strands to maintain continuity.  I mention this because the punch down connections in the back of a faceplate will readily displace the wire insulation on a solid single core, but can sometimes fail to penetrate the insulation on the more flexible multistrand, so if you use multistrand into the faceplate try to **keep it taut** as you punch, and **punch down repeatedly** to ensure a good connection.

You can only be really sure of success across all pairs by using a continuity tester.

HTH